# What happens to a custodial brokerage account when child reaches the age of majority?

Tags: united-states, brokerage, children

My children have custodial brokerage accounts in their names. When they reach the age of majority in our state will the account change from a custodial account to a standard brokerage account or will a new account need to be opened?

Edit: The account is currently with Charles Schwab

Comment: The answer might depend on the state that you live in.

Comment: We are located in Iowa.